# About SQL with time process

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following information, but only time no date (time continuous), but I have a date basis points.

```
time T1 T2 T3 T4
---------------------------------------------------------------------
14:36:11.000 24 28 23 35
20:46:20.000 27 28 27 32
00:07:33.000 24 27 23 38
01:36:20.000 94 28 27 32
03:46:50.000 24 28 23 37
07:58:20.000 64 58 27 32
15:29:25.000 24 23 27 32
01:15:32.000 44 28 27 39
```

IF I now the fist Row's Datetime is '2013-06-03 14:36:11.000'. How can I get that data：

```
Datetime T1 T2 T3 T4
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-06-03 14:36:11.000 24 28 23 35
2013-06-03 20:46:20.000 27 28 27 32
2013-06-04 00:07:33.000 24 27 23 38
2013-06-04 01:36:20.000 94 28 27 32
2013-06-04 03:46:50.000 24 28 23 37
2013-06-04 07:58:20.000 64 58 27 32
2013-06-04 15:29:25.000 24 23 27 32
2013-06-05 01:15:32.000 44 28 27 39
```

Comment: This seems really error-prone. What if there is a 24 hour gap, for example?

Comment: It's machine data log.It runs all day.Perhaps we can ignore this problem.

Comment: What are the rows being sorted by in the first query, to let you know that they are in chronological order if you have no day?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4vcUW4kXetldVJJS1ZBbnBBRGs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can the logger be edited to also insert the day? (Or use a trigger to add it during the insert?) If so, why not add in the days in application code rather than tsql and thereafter alter the database column so it is full datetime and the problem will no longer exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      [time] VARCHAR(12)
    , T1 INT
    , T2 INT
    , T3 INT
    , T4 INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp ([time], T1, T2, T3, T4)
VALUES 
    ('14:36:11.000', 24, 28, 23, 35),
    ('20:46:20.000', 27, 28, 27, 32),
    ('00:07:33.000', 24, 27, 23, 38),
    ('01:36:20.000', 94, 28, 27, 32),
    ('03:46:50.000', 24, 28, 23, 37),
    ('07:58:20.000', 64, 58, 27, 32),
    ('15:29:25.000', 24, 23, 27, 32),
    ('01:15:32.000', 44, 28, 27, 39)

DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2013-06-03'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
          tt = [time]
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
        , T1, T2, T3, T4
    FROM @temp t
),
cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT t1.*, [shift] = 0 
    FROM cte t1
    WHERE t1.rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.*, [shift] = 
                        CASE WHEN cte2.tt > cte.tt 
                            THEN [shift] + 1 
                            ELSE [shift] 
                        END 
    FROM cte2
    JOIN cte ON cte2.rn = cte.rn - 1
)
SELECT [time] = DATEADD(DAY, shift, @Date + ' ' + tt), T1, T2, T3, T4 
FROM cte2
```

**Results:**

```
time                    T1          T2          T3          T4
----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2013-06-03 14:36:11.000 24          28          23          35
2013-06-03 20:46:20.000 27          28          27          32
2013-06-04 00:07:33.000 24          27          23          38
2013-06-04 01:36:20.000 94          28          27          32
2013-06-04 03:46:50.000 24          28          23          37
2013-06-04 07:58:20.000 64          58          27          32
2013-06-04 15:29:25.000 24          23          27          32
2013-06-05 01:15:32.000 44          28          27          39
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution is for MySql :

```
SELECT (@var:=if(time(@var)<=b.time,timestamp(date(@var),b.time),
     timestamp(date(date_add(@var, interval 1 day)),b.time))) as Datetime , 
     b.T1,b.T2,b.T3,b.T4
FROM test.YOURTABLE b, (select @var:='2013-06-03 00:00:00') a
```

Comment: "This solution is for MySQL" - and yet question is clearly tagged SQL Server!

Comment: @MitchWheat: This may not be the answer to the question, but it certainly brings the OP 90% closer to an answer. Others with SQL Server experience could use this as a starting point. It is very clever and certainly is a welcome contribution, especially from a new user.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  +1 !